# Getting IOException in Android Recorder Program

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

Start Recording function -

```
  private fun startRecording() {
    if (checkpermissions()) {
        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
            setOutputFile(fileName)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

            try {
                prepare()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed")
            }
        }
    } else {
        requestpermissions()
    }
```

}

Checking Permission function :-

```
private  fun checkpermissions(): Boolean {
        val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, RECORD_AUDIO)
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTE
      }
```

Requesting Permission Function :-

```
private fun requestpermissions()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this@MainActivity,
            arrayOf(RECORD_AUDIO, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE
        )
    }
```

Manifest permission taken by me :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>
```

Program is not asking for any Storage permission. While Running any App, Getting IOException in startRecording() function.
App is not saving audio file in its storage. May be due to this I am getting this exception.
Please help.

Comment: Please delete app from your device and install again and check it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use the new api for get permission :
[Runtime permission with new api](https://medium.com/@ajinkya.kolkhede1/requesting-runtime-permissions-using-new-activityresult-api-cb6116551f00)